# Liberty Profile Configuration Editor within Eclipse MARS no longer appears

Tags: eclipse, websphere-liberty

The Liberty Profile Configuration Editor no longer appears. All was working great and now all I get is the XML editor. The option for the Configuration Editor is still in the context menu but I always get the XML editor.

I would like the option back. Is there a HOW TO?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the version of the Liberty plugins you have is not compatible with Eclipse Mars. You should update it, easiest way is probably via Eclipse Marketplace. Here's what looks like the latest Liberty Profile tools in the marketplace: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-liberty-profile-developer-tools-0

Answer (score 0):

This also could be as simple as the related editor for server.xml was messed up.  If you click on the server.xml file, and use context menu "Open With..." Do you still see "Liberty Profile Configuration Editor" in the list?

- Chuck

Comment: Chuck, The editor still appears in the list. I have deselected and reselected it numerous times.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions. The issue persists. This appears in the .metatdata: !ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-08-18 11:50:19.760
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\djonio'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options....

Answer (score 0):

- Is the Design tab still showing but the design view displays an error when you click on it?  If so, what is the error?
- Are there any messages in the .log file (`<your workspace>/.metadata/.log`)
- Is it not working on some particular files or not working at all, for instance, if you create a new file does it open with the configuration file editor?  To create a new file, right click on your server folder in the explorer view and select `New -> Liberty Profile Configuration File`.  Give it a name like test.xml and click Finish.

One thing you could try is to regenerate the runtime cache and see if that helps:

```
Window -> Show View -> Other -> Server -> Runtime Explorer
Right click on runtime in Runtime Explorer view and select Edit
Click on Advanced options in the dialog
Click the Refresh button
Wait for the refresh timestamp to be updated
```

or:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment -> SELECT YOUR RUNTIME -> CLICK Edit -> CLICK Advanced options... -> CLICK Refresh
Wait for the refresh timestamp to be updated
```